# Use QML delegate on QListWidget

Tags: qt, qml

I'm using a Qlistwidget and I want to use custom delegates. 
It's possible to use QML as QListWidget delegate?
I know how to integrate QML into a widget application but I cannot realize how to use it as delegate.

Comment: I don't know if what you're trying to achieve is possible, but you could use a QML ListView with QML delegates and integrate it in your widget application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be possible, if you can use [QQuickWidget](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qquickwidget.html) as the delegate. If you've already managed to integrate QML into your application, then it shouldn't be hard to try.

Don't do it though, really. Just use one or the other.